# Delphi Text Files get NULLS (0's) written to them instead of text

Tags: delphi

Unfortunately this question may be a bit vague, I have a problem that I am finding difficult to describe, it is intermittent and I cannot reproduce it myself, I am just hoping that someone else has seen something like it before.

My application has quite a lot of text and ini files that get written when it closes down.  Typically this would be in response to a Close event, but may also be triggered by a WM_ENDSESSION.  Unfortunately at the moment I am not sure if both or only one of these events can result in the problem I am about to describe, because I have been unable to reproduce this problem myself.

The issue I have is that for some users some of the text and ini files end up being written as NULLs.  The file sizes end up looking about right, but instead of text, every character is written as a x00.  So instead of 500 bytes of regular ASCII text I end up with 500 x00's.  I also have an application log file that can sometimes end up with nulls written to it also.  However the logging of x00's to the log file does not necessarily correspond to the exact same time as x00's were written to the config files.

For my files I am using TmemIniFile or TstringList which means that ultimately a Tstrings.SaveToFile is being called for all of my config files.

```
sl:=TstringList.Create;
try
  SourceList.GetSpecificSubset(sl);
  AppLogLogLine('Commands: Saving Always Available list.  List has '+inttostr(sl.Count)+' commands.');
  sl.SaveToFile(fn);
finally
  sl.Free;
end;
```

But then I also have instance where I would already have a TstringList in memory and I just call SaveToFile on it.  For TmemIniFile the structure would look similar to above.  In some instances I may have an outer loop to write multiple lists.  Some of those will result in files being written correctly, some will be full of 00's.

EDIT: GetSpecificSubset is simply a function that will populate "sl" with a list of command names.  I have "GetAllUsersCommands", "GetHiddenCommands", "GetAlwaysVisibleCommands" etc.  Note that my log file also writes this kind of thing, as a check for how big those lists are:

16/10/2013 11:17:49 AM: Commands: Saving Any User list.  List has 8 commands.
16/10/2013 11:17:49 AM: Commands: Saving Always Visible list.  List has 17 commands.
16/10/2013 11:17:49 AM: Commands: Saving Always Hidden list.  List has 2 commands.

I accidentally left the logging line out of the code above.  So this log line is the last thing written before calling Tstrings.SaveToFile, and at that point it thinks it has data.  Even if somehow each line of text were NULLs, I would still expect to see x13x10 in the files, but that is not happening.

Here's a screen cap from a HEX editor:
[image: Screen Cap from HEX editor]

EDIT 2: I just realised I left off a very important piece of information.  This is only intermittent.  It works 99% of the time.  When saving files at shutdown it might not even be all files.  Even if I have a loop saving multiple similar files, some may work fine and others may fail.

Comment: You need to do some debugging.

Comment: Are you doing the saving in finalization areas of some unit?

Comment: Delphi text files don't just "get nulls written to them". Something in your code is doing it, or you're writing something with Unicode characters (which would possibly write some nulls as part of the text, but wouldn't leave the file "full of 00s". You'll need to show some content from the file (a hex dump is fine, if you properly format it). I don't know if Unicode is the case, because you failed to mention anywhere in your post or tags which specific version of Delphi you're using (2007 and earlier are non-Unicode, 2009 and later are Unicode).

Comment: Are you sure its even running?  One obscure gotchya when responding to a system shutdown is that the work has to be done *very quickly* or the OS will just kill your application off.  So you may need to check that isnt whats happening.  If that ends up being the problem, you may want to move your ini saving out of the closedown routines, and make them save when values are changed.  Other than that, you may need to look at sl.Text to make sure you actually have the content you think you have in that list.

Comment: Have you run the code under debug and checked that variable sl actually contains the text you expect. What does GetSpecificSubset do?

Comment: The only way the `TStringList.SaveTo...()` methods would write all nulls is if the `String` values in the list are not empty but consist of all null characters to begin with.  `TStringList` does not create its own nulls.

Comment: Delphi strings have a length prefix at the start of the string. They do not rely on zero termination only. If you mix code that depends on zero termination with code that uses `AString.Length` you'll end up with messed up data.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I know, and I have, but since I can't reproduce the problem myself it's not easy.  So I write to alog file at any stage that I require, trying to track down what is going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I get that.  But as I mentioned I am also using TmemIniFile as well, and even if I (am allowed to) were doing WriteString("","","") then I would still end up with:

[]
=

And that includes CRLF at the end of each line.  But like I said, the files are full of x00, nothing but.

Comment: @KenWhite: I could post a file if you like. But as I said the files are full of x00s.  I maybe did the wrong thing by saying NULLs.  I have looked at the files in a hex editor.  Everything is 0.  No CRs, No LFs, just x00.  I am using D2010.  Default is to save as plain ANSI/ASCII, no BOM, that is fine for what I have.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Unfortunately I have a lot of stuff to save. I did have a thought at one stage that this was some kind of issue with Delayed disk writes or something, but that was pure speculation.  I have logging that tells me how many items are in the lists before it saves them.  I will update the question with a little more on that.

Comment: In what directory are you saving the files? Do the user have write access? What is?

Comment: @Jenakai: the only time I have ever seen files with all nulls in them was due to either HDD failures or other external interference that corrupted the files outside of the app that created the files.  So it was not a coding problem.

Comment: @DavidG: I just realised that I forgot to say this was an intermittent problem.  99% of the time it works fine.  So write access is OK, because it usually works fine.